# Trying to implement a maths equation in a method

Tags: math, methods

Code a method called calcSeries that calculates and returns the value of y in the following series:

y=1+∑ni=1i2i∗x
where n and x are two input integers and y is the returned double value.

Example:

Input: x=8, n=4

So, the series is y=1+1/(1∗8)+2^2/(2∗8)+3^2/(3∗8)+4^2/(4∗8)
Output: 2.25

I am having trouble with going about how to design the code. So far I have:

```
public double calcSeries(int n, int x){
        double y = 0.0;
        int a = 1;
        double b = Math.pow(n,2)/(n*x);
        for (int i = 1; i < (n + 1); i++) {
            
        }
        return y;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already written most of it. Just added the declaration of `b` inside the loop, since it's value depends on the current `i`.

```
public double calcSeries(int n, int x){
        double y = 1.0;
        for (int i = 1; i < (n + 1); i++) {
            double b = Math.pow(i,2)/(i*x);
            y += b;
        }
        return y;
    }
```

Comment: If it solves your purpose, please mark it as the accepted answer